# Change [scheme] tag to [scheme-lisp]

Tags: feature-request, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

It seems that every day or two someone marks a questions with the tag [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme), when what they really mean is [url-scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-scheme) or [schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schema). It may help people self correct more if the official tag were [scheme-lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme-lisp) and [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme) was simply a synonym for it. When they look at the tag that gets filled in, they will see that it is not what they meant and correct it.

Maybe that isn't the best idea, but I think something should be done since enough people are unfamiliar with the Scheme language that the tag is being used improperly all the time and needs to be corrected.

Thoughts? Alternatives?